# WindowBuilder "Cannot create extension" error?

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

At my high school, we have started using swing while utilizing Eclipse's free WindowBuilder plugin.  However, when I open it on my computer at home, I am presented with this error:

[image]

Do you guys know how I can resolve this issue?  I've already reinstalled WindowBuilder.

Thanks!

Comment: click on detail and show it here.Also show class that you are trying to open in it.

Comment: @TomasBisciak

Here is what is shown:

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot create extension
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:296)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)

Answer (score 1):

Check what Runtime Environment you are using and whether it is compatible with the extension version, in addition check whether your WindowBuilder extension is compatible with your version of Eclipse.

When I had this problem, I was able to create a WindowBuilder class file and it worked fine. I restarted Eclipse and I received that error. All I had to do was update my Java Runtime Environment to 1.7 and WindowBuilder returned to nominal operation.